# NullReferenceException in Form.OnVisibleChanged

Tags: .net, winforms

On some computers, our Windows Forms application crashes every time when opening certain Forms with this call stack:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.WndProc(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Null reference exceptions don't normally indicate bad inheritance as you've suggested with your answer. Have you implemented Form.OnVisibleChanged, and if so, can we see your code?

Comment: No, the method is not overriden. The problem is `Control control = this.AcceptButton as Control` with no further null check in `Form.OnVisibleChanged` implementation (in a branch, that changes the mouse cursor position if enabled in mouse settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the feature **Automatically move pointer to the default button** is enabled in Control Panel, application crashes in `Form.OnVisibleChanged` when Form's `AcceptButton` does not derive from `Windows.Forms.Control`.

<del>This is clearly a bug in Windows Forms, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't say that `IButtonControl AcceptButton` must derive from `Control`.</del>

Comment: It says: "Allows a **control** to act like a button".  Given the outcome, I'd say it is pretty clear what the word "control" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Good point. Still though, throwing NullReferenceException under some improbable conditions is far from the best way to enforce this so-so documented requirement.